# How can you determine the URL of a youtube channel based on the channel ID?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-channels

It seems that there should be a way to do youtube.com/user/{channel id} . but I can't figure it out. I also have the GooglePlusUserId (when available) to use.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since channel URLs aren't returned in any of the parts of the [channels resource](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels), your best bet is to construct it yourself as `http://www.youtube.com/channel/UC...`, where `UC...` is the channel id.

I'd think that would be fairly future-proof.

Edit: I hear that YouTube.com URLs might get added to v3 responses at some point in the near future, and if they do, I'd obviously recommend using that instead of constructing them manually. I'll try to remember to update this answer if they are, but you can follow https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/revision_history to check as well.

Comment: Thank you! yep, just needed `channel` instead of `user` in the URL.